# Aggregating grouped data with repeating data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions, aggregate, ssrs-2012

I am trying to figure out how to aggregate the number of hours a person worked that is repeated by each fringe code that they have.

The data looks like this

```
Company Code Employee Code   Employee Name   Hours   Fringe Code Fringe Amount 
030          12345           Joe Blow        8       VAC             10.00
030          12345           Joe Blow        8       DUE              5.00
030          12345           Joe Blow        8       INTDUE           2.00
030          54698           Alan Low        8       VAC             10.00
030          54698           Alan Low        8       DUE              5.00
030          54698           Alan Low        8       INTDUE           2.00
```

Now the total number of hours should by 16.  In the report I have grouped the following fields Company Code, Employee Code, Employee Name, Hours so that they only appear once (not sure how to show that).

I tried to do the following

```
Sum(FIRST(Fields!Hours.Value, "Employee_Name") , "Company_Code")
```

but I get an error saying that the value is using a First aggregate in an outer aggregate and that they cannot be specified as nested aggregates.

Any ideas?

Comment: How Fringes `10,5,2` add to 16? You should include your desire output

Comment: `Field!Hours.Value` smells like SSRS. No SSRS tag? Please note that aggregating in SSRS is different from SQL server query

Comment: Are there 3 Fringe Codes for every employee?  You could sum on Hours and divide by 3 ....

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I am trying to add the hours not fringe amount.

Comment: @AnnL. No there can be different number of fringe codes by grouping.

Comment: Thank you for providing input table, please do provide a tabular depiction of expected output so that we can help you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want so I guess a possible result scenario.

I 've reproduced the providing input table.

[image]

Using this tablix data settings:

[image]

Add this code to the report. This function will flag those rows that must be summed.

```
Dim groups As System.Collections.Hashtable

Function MyFunc(ByVal group As Object) As integer
dim flag as integer
        If (groups Is Nothing) Then
            groups = New System.Collections.Hashtable
        End If
        If (Not groups.Contains(group)) Then
                flag = 1
                groups.Add(group, nothing) 
        else
                flag = 0  
        End If

            MyFunc = flag

End Function
```

And this expression in the tablix textbox you want to put the sum.

```
=sum(val(iif(Code.MyFunc(Fields!Employee_Code.Value) = 1, Fields!Hours.Value, 0)))
```

You'll get this preview

[image]

Let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had issues with some of the above suggestions but I figured out how to solve the problem.

I used the following equation:

=SUM(MAX(Fields!Regular_Hours.Value, "Employee_Code","Company_Code")

Thus I used the MAX function to get only one occurrence per Employee Code and then did a sum of that one occurrence over the Company Code grouping.

Thanks for your guys help!